# Onchange doesn't fire?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Its probably something really stupid that I'm doing but I searched a lot and for the life of me I don't get whats wrong (new in web design/programming), and I know it should fire when textbox loses focus but it doesn't:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ask9</title>

<script>
function changeColor(){

var x=document.getElementById("box").value;
if(isNaN(x)==false)
{
    body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}
else if(isNaN(x)==true)
{
    body.style.backgroundColor="green";
}
else
{
    body.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 

    <input type="text" id="box" onchange="changeColor()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future you can debug problems like this using the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body` isn't defined - you probably mean `document.body` or `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` - see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrrpM/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ask9</title>
<script>
function changeColor() { 
    var x=document.getElementById("box").value;
    if(isNaN(x)==false)
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    }
    else if(isNaN(x)==true)
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";
    }
    /* // will never occur, isNaN() always returns a boolean
    else 
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }*/
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="box" onchange="changeColor()"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: body.style.backgroundColor=document.getElementById("box").value; i did this in a function and it worked...why?

Comment: @user2874565: if you did something like `var body = document.body`, then it would have worked.

Comment: @user2874565 some browsers might have been "forgiving" enough to make the check and fix the code for you; you must not rely on this though, modern browsers require correct JavaScript and won't fix it for you.

Comment: I should start using debbugers for web design as well i guess.